# HashMap put in a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

```
for (int i = 0; i < projectList.size(); i++) {
        String projectName = projectList.get(i);
        String url = "https://api.github.com/repos/apache/" + projectName + "/commits";

        try {
            data = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
            System.out.println(url);
            // System.out.println(data);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        objArray = new JSONArray(data);

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < objArray.length(); i1++) {
            obj = objArray.getJSONObject(i1);               

            if (!obj.isNull("committer")) {
                obj1 = obj.getJSONObject("committer");
                commiterName = obj1.getString("login");
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
            if (!UserCommitCount.containsKey(commiterName)) {
                UserCommitCount.put(commiterName, 1);
            } else {
                UserCommitCount.put(commiterName, UserCommitCount.get(commiterName) + 1);
            }

        }
        UserCommitCount = sortByComparator(UserCommitCount, DESC);
        UserCommitCount = resizeUserCommitCount(UserCommitCount);
        printHashMap(UserCommitCount);
        System.out.println(projectName + "!!!!");
        printHashMap(UserCommitCount);

        RepoNameCommitterMap.put(projectName, UserCommitCount);
        UserCommitCount.clear();
        System.out.println(projectName+ "AFTER");
        printHashMap(UserCommitCount);
        printNestedHashMap(RepoNameCommitterMap);
    }
```

So im trying to store data in a Hashmap and the  output is like this

```
https://api.github.com/repos/apache/zookeeper/commits

hanm - 4

anmolnar - 23

lvfangmin - 3

zookeeper!!!!

hanm - 4

anmolnar - 23

lvfangmin - 3


zookeeper - {}
https://api.github.com/repos/apache/camel/commits

davsclaus - 9

oscerd - 20

PascalSchumacher - 1

camel!!!!

davsclaus - 9

oscerd - 20

PascalSchumacher - 1

camelAFTER

zookeeper - {davsclaus=9, oscerd=20, PascalSchumacher=1}

camel - {}

https://api.github.com/repos/apache/httpd/commits

minfrin - 1

elukey - 2

ylavic - 6

jfclere - 3

notroj - 4

jimjag - 1

httpd!!!!

minfrin - 1

elukey - 2

ylavic - 6

jfclere - 3

notroj - 4

jimjag - 1

httpdAFTER

zookeeper - {davsclaus=9, oscerd=20, PascalSchumacher=1}

camel - {minfrin=1, elukey=2, ylavic=6, jfclere=3, notroj=4, jimjag=1}

httpd - {}
```

And goes on. You see that in the first put command key is put but the hashMap does not and it shifts the next iteration. I could not understand why is that happens. Could anyone help me fix it ?

In the First iteration ReponameCommiter.put, puts the name of the repo but does not put the userCommitCount Map.

Comment: "You see that in the first put command key is put but the hashMap does not and it shifts the next iteration" Can you rephase this? I don't know what you're saying

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: so it should like this zookeeper - { hanm = 4,anmolnar = 23, lvangfin = 3 } instead of zookeeper - { } these 3 (hanm,anmolar and lvangfin) discarded somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the hash map twice:

```
printHashMap(UserCommitCount);
System.out.println(projectName + "!!!!");
printHashMap(UserCommitCount);
```

Perhaps you should print only once?